# Ruby: How to convert a date-time string to a floating point number in epoch time?

Tags: ruby

The string is `Feb 1, 2014 06:47:42.93`, want to convert to `1391237262.93`. I searched a few methods, but none matching this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Time::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse), a Ruby stdlib library function, then call `to_f` on the resulting `Time` object.

```
require 'time'
str = 'Feb 1, 2014 06:47:42.93'
Time.parse(str).to_f
```